# Не работает C=int(k[0])

Tags: python

```
N=int(input())
K=input().split()
print(K[0])
C=0
Z=-99999999
X=99999999
while K!='':
    C=int(K[0])
    if C%2==0 and C>=Z:
        Z=C
    if C%2!=0 and C<=X:
        X=C
    K=K[1:]
print(Z, X)
```

8 строка выдаёт ошибку

Comment: Вообще нужно приводить и пример ввода, который приводит к ошибке. Мы должны гадать, что вы вводите?

Comment: Пишите в питоне просто `while K:` - работает, пока список не пустой.

Answer (score 0):

а у вас никогда вот этого не будет:

```
while K!=''
```

у вас в конце останется

```
while K!=[]
```

и при этом вы обращаетесь к 0 элементу (проверка же не сработала и не произошло выхода из while)

Comment: Спасибо большое